# Can't find my jQuery on page? is it displaying loaded data behind other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So my basic goal here is to simply use a jQuery style function to display the word hello. I want this so that in the future I can personalize the hello . "Hello " + $username. I have attached my code.

```
<h3 onLoad = "helloMessage();" id="id"> </h3>
```

my .js file looks like this,

```
function helloMessage()
    {
    document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello ";
    }
```

My page is not throwing me any errors but when I try to find the element `h3` it simply gives me an area on the page with no "Hello " message? Is this because my "Hello " is returning within the `h3` field?

```
<h3 "Hello "> </h3>
```

Edit: I appreciate I was incorrect before.

Now I currently have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.helloMessage = function(){ 
        alert ('Hello'); 
    }
    $(".hello").ready(function(){
        $.fn.helloMessage();
    });
});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<h3 class="hello"> </h3>
```

This is all fine and working. However I want the "Hello " to be displayed on the webpage and not as an alert. If I try to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.helloMessage = function(){ 
        return ('Hello'); 
    }
    $(".hello").ready(function(){
        $.fn.helloMessage();
    });
});
```

Final Edit:
Thank you rory, your thorough answer helped me to figure out where I was going wrong. Additionally YamneZ thanks for helping regarding the display issue.

Comment: Okay, apologies. This is my first time trying to implement jquery and I'm having a tough time with it. I've managed to implement this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `onload` attribute on `h3` elements. If you want to run that function when the page loads, call it directly:

```js
function helloMessage() {
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello";
}

helloMessage();
```

```html
<h3 id="id"></h3>
```

Your JS needs to be put just before `</body>` for this to work, though. Otherwise you'll need to attach a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler to the document and put the code in there, like this:

```js
function helloMessage() {
  document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = "Hello";
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  helloMessage();
});
```

```html
<h3 id="id"></h3>
```

Finally note that there's nothing to do with jQuery in this question, despite the title. If you want to do this in jQuery it would look like this:

```js
function helloMessage() {
  $('#id').html('Hello');
}

jQuery(($) => {
  helloMessage();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 id="id"></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rory's answer fits your need. If you want to use jQuery for your code, you can also use:

```
// This code means the page is loaded
$(function() {
  // Modify the text of the H3
  $('h3#id').text('Hello ');
});
```